# Functions that are only second-preimage resistant?

Tags: 2nd-preimage-resistance

Are there functions that satisfy the second-preimage resistance property without satisfying the others (preimage and collision resistance) ?

I'm looking about such functions that compress data (exit the identity function).

Comment: @fgrieu I don't see how proving that helps.

Comment: Thanks I update my question because I thought about function that are compressing...

Comment: @CodesInChaos: you are right that proving _collision resistance implies second-preimage resistance_ won't help.

Comment: Hint: assume a compressing function that satisfies all three properties; tweak it by changing the image of a single element to break collision resistance.

Comment: Such functions exist ? I've seen universal one way hash functions, but this one satisfy one-wayness, a property that I don't need.

Comment: @fgrieu, I don't understand why the fact to tweak it by changing the image of a ""single"" element break collision resistance. And why this responds to my question ? Thank you.

Comment: Dingo, you might want to state what your actual goal is. Avoiding to use a "normal"  cryptographic hash function? Or do you actually want to have something that is not collision resistant? As practical example of such a function, you can use MD5, which is broken for collision resistance but preimage resistance is still considered okay-ish.

Comment: @tylo Yes I would like to use something different from a cryptographic hash function, but having compressing and second preimage properties... I would like something like a mathematical function, but not a cryptographically designed hash function.

Comment: I don't think that there is such a function. Noncryptographic hash functions are neither designed for nor examined w.r.t. preimage resistance. Either you care for cryptographic aspects and then you need to do it properly, or you don't. I don't think there is a middle ground.

Answer (score 7):

Take a function $H:\mathbb S\to\{0,1\}^k$ where $\mathbb S$ is a large finite subset of $\{0,1\}^*$, such that $H$ "*compress data*" [however this is defined], and $H$ is [conjectured] collision-resistant [thus second-preimage-resistant] and first-preimage-resistant; e.g., SHA-512, for $k=512$. Let $«0»$ and $«1»$ be two public distinct elements of $\mathbb S$. Define $H':\mathbb S\to\{0,1\}^k$ by
$$H'(M)= \begin{cases}H(«1»)&\text{if }M\text{ is }«0»\\H(M)&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

This $H'$ is compressing, and not collision-resistant [argument: $H'(«0»)=H'(«1»)$]. However $H'$ remains preimage-resistant, both first and second [argument: preimage resistance is defined for random message, thus the minor change we made to $H$ in order to build $H'$ does not matter, for odds that a random choice of message hits $«0»$ or $«1»$ are negligible].

Hence $H'$ is second-preimage resistant, but not collision resistant. Which answers the question by the affirmative [I'm reading "*without satisfying the others*" as "*not (satisfying the others*)"].

Note: I conjecture without proof that the answer is negative when reading "*without satisfying **any of** the others*".

---

Informal definitions: a function $F$ is

- ***collision-resistant*** when a [computationally bounded] adversary can't exhibit any $(a,b)$ with $a\ne b$ and $F(a)=F(b)$;
- ***first-preimage-resistant*** when, given $f$ determined as $F(a)$ for an unknown random $a$, a [computationally bounded] adversary can't [with sizable odds] exhibit any $b$ with $F(b)=f$;
- ***second-preimage-resistant*** when, given a random $a$, a [computationally bounded] adversary can't [with sizable odds] exhibit any $b$ with $a\ne b$ and $F(a)=F(b)$.

Note: these definitions are a compromise between simplicity and precision, but lacking about what *random $a$*, *sizable odds* and *computationally bounded* means. However they can be made formal by making $F$ a parameterized function family; and adding some appropriate parameterized upper bound for the size of that *random $a$* when the input domain $\mathbb S$ is unbounded.

Comment: @otus: yes, $H′(0)=H′(1)$ imply $H'$ isn't collision resistant; that's because from the definition of $H'$ we know a particular $(a,b)$ [that is, $(0,1)$] such that $a\ne b$ and $F(a)=F(b)$. We assume the adversary knows this definition too, and is at least as smart as we are.

Comment: The definition of collision resistance means "find two values, which result in the same hash". If such a value is already baked in the definition of the function, collision resistance is broken. Additionally, the (small) difference between first and second preimage resistance becomes clear when you look for the $a\neq b$ statement, although in real functions are considered pretty much the same. But for example the identity function is collision resistant and second preimage resistant but not first preimage resistant.

Comment: My point was that there's a reason rigorous definitions  of collision resistance consider families of hash functions. However, with your added definitions your proof is clearly correct, so I've removed the comment.